# Pandas Series.isnull() for custom "NA" definition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isnull

I'am quite new to pandas, trying to identify missing values in a dataset (cells in table).

Here is code example:

`total = DataFrame.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)`

But the problem that I don't have "NA" or " " values as empty, in my case value "undefined" so it count like not empty.

DataFrame string example:

`id       name country age        sex     phone`
`41113    Ann  US      undefined  female  undefined`

How can I modify `isnull()` or is there some better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ne` and `all`:

```
df[df.ne("undefined").all(axis=1)]
```